# I have Advagg Module for Drupal 7.x and i have many files in folders advagg_js/css.... why?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have `Drupal 7.x` and `Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation`   7.x-2.7

In folders advagg_js and advagg_css (path is sites/default/files) i have 
I have too many identical files and i don't understand why...

This is a name of file in advagg_css :

```
      css____tQ6DKNpjnnLOLLOo1chze6a0EuAzr40c2JW8LEnlk__CmbidT93019ZJXjBPnKuAOSV78GHKPC3vgAjyUWRvNg__U78DXVtmNgrsprQhJ0bcjElTm2p5INlkJg6oQm4a72o
```

How can I delete all these files without doing damage?

Maybe in `performance/advagg/operations` in box **Cron Maintenance Tasks** i must check

**Clear All Stale Files**

*Remove all stale files. Scan all files in the advagg_css/js directories and remove the ones that have not been accessed in the last 30 days.*

????

I hope you can help me...

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why would you want to delete them?  Advagg automatically cleans out old aggregates after a predetermined amount of time.  You can access these settings under `/admin/config/development/performance/advagg` in the *Cron Options* section.

Answer (score 0):

I can guarantee that there are very few duplicate files in those directories. If you really want, you can manually delete every file in there; a lot of them will be generated again so you're back to having a lot of files (the css/js files get auto created on demand, just like image styles). AdvAgg is very good at preventing a 404 from happening when requesting an aggregated css/js file. You can adjust how old a file needs to be in order for it to be considered "stale". Inside of the core [drupal_delete_file_if_stale()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_delete_file_if_stale/7.x) function is the `drupal_stale_file_threshold` variable. Changing this inside of your settings.php file to something like 2 days `$conf['drupal_stale_file_threshold'] = 172800;` will make Drupal more aggressive in terms of removing aggregated css and js files.

Long term if you want to reduce the number of different css/js files from being created you'll need to reduce the number of combinations/variations that are possible with your css and js assets. On the "admin/config/development/performance/advagg/bundler" page under raw grouping info it will tell you how many different groupings are currently possible, take that number and multiply it by the number of bundles (usually 2-6 if following a guide like this https://www.drupal.org/node/2493801 or 6-12 if using the default settings) and that's the number of files that can currently be generated. Multiply it by 2 for gzip. On one of our sites that gives us over 4k files.

In terms of file names the first base64 group is the file name, second base64 group are the file contents, and the third base64 group are the advagg settings. This allows for the aggregates contents to be recreated by just knowing the filename as all this additional info is stored in the database.